# Precisamos melhorar

Tags: discussion

Analisando as informações da figura a seguir, podemos perceber que a comunidade precisa melhorar. Acredito que iremos alcançar as metas, mas é necessários convidar outras pessoas para que se juntem a nós.

[image]

Quando os indicadores forem alcançados deixamos de ser Beta?

Quanto tempo ainda temos?

Comment: Concordo. Entretanto o(a) Pops alertou em [outro meta post](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/172/3) similar a este o seguinte: _"I love the spirit here, but please don't focus too much on the stats on that page. A few months ago, we updated how we look at the health of beta sites, and most of those numbers turned out to be less important than we thought they were in the past. We just haven't gotten around to updating what gets displayed there, yet."_

Comment: Eu ainda não tive paciência para ler o link que ele(a) passou: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/229289 mas eu também acho que eles já poderiam ter atualizado logo essa página para nos ajudar a entender o que é importante então.

Comment: @Math concordo. Pelo que eu entendi o importante é ter bom conteúdo e uma boa base de utilizadores habituais para que sejam respondidas as perguntas dos novatos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PT**

Estamos a melhorar de dia para dia, as perguntas vão aparecendo, as visitas também, por isso tentem divulgar o site o mais que possam. Se as pessoas se habituarem a vir cá perguntar sobre o Português teremos um site saudável de certeza.

**EN**

We are improving day by day, more questions, more visits. So we have to share the site always as we can. If people get used to come here to ask about the Portuguese Language certainly we will have a healthy site .

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

After holidays we have improved:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>